# S3 performance Best Pratices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We created a datalake on AWS S3, and for now we used only one bucket, our data lake is divided by some areas:
s3://bucket/landing/subject/table
s3://bucket/raw/subject/table
s3://bucket/refined/subject/table
s3://bucket/staging/subject/table

So, I'm reading about s3 performance best practices, and some people advise to divide the datalake in different buckets and for specific cases have one bucket for a big table.
Our datalake is very small now, but our company is growing fast...so what are the best practices to don't have performance problems in the future?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html

I'm reading about the limits, but what is prefix?

s3://bucket/landing/subject/table1
s3://bucket/landing/subject/table2

Two prefix? or Only one?

thank you.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html

> However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3
> console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects.
> Amazon S3 does this by using a shared name prefix for objects (that
> is, objects have names that begin with a common string). Object names
> are also referred to as key names.

So a prefix would be everything before the last slash in the key name.